# jQuery and DataTables - Is it possible to re-call the previous AJAX command?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm use jQuery and jQuery DataTables.

The issue I'm having is that, is it possible in jQuery Ajax to recall the DataTable's ajax to get data again?

The reason is:

If a person has TWO webpage of the same table opened up.

If on one table, he changed the columns for the table, the column names syncs to the database on the webpage. Hence the second webpage that contains the same table will have inconsistency (since the columns doesn't match with the database).

I'm trying to detect that on the server side code when the get request's columns array is different from what is stored in the database.

For example:

1# Webpage has a get request columns[0] = "column 1", columns[1] = "column 2"

Checks with database, and database says there are two columns, with the names of "column 1" and "column 2". Finds that the columns are consistent, and sends data to the user.

At #1 Webpage the user changed the columns to 3 columns, and it automatically syncs to the database.

On the other hand, #2 webpage is idle, but when fnDraw is called, it notice that the get requests columns and the is different in the database. Now it needs to recall the ajax function until it does not return undesired response status.

Currently I have my code:

```
var table = $('#'+String(response.chartID[i])).DataTable({
    stateSave: true,
    aoColumnDefs: aryJSONColTable,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    bDestroy: true,
    "scrollX": true,
    ajax:
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url:"ajax_retrieveMainChartData/",
        dataType: 'json',
        data:
        {
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrftoken,
            'activeTab':activeTab,
            'chartID':response.chartID[i],
        },
    },
})
.on('xhr.dt', function(e, settings, response)
{
    if (response.status == "refresh")
    {
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

I had already implemented the checks in my server side. But for my front-end, basically I do a location.reload when there are a mismatch in my column from the server and serverside.

Hence when the same person accesses the webpage on two places, and edits one table's column. To maintain consistency, I will use a location.reload() to do a refresh on the user's webpage.

However, I only want to refresh one of the DataTable and not the whole webpage.

Is it possible to recall the ajax for DataTable when something goes wrong?

I was going to put a while loop around the variable table, but that could mess up the table since Ajax is asynchronous.

I was thinking about something like this

```
$(this).DataTable().destroy();
$(this).empty();
$(this).refresh(); <-- This function does not exist
```

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have multiple datatables on the same page.

How about when a user modifies the columns on one you update the properties of the other and tell it to redraw?

```
var t1 = $('#table1').dataTable();
var t2 = $('#table2').dataTable();
```

Let's say you have a function that watches for changes to `t1`. To update `t2` run `t2.fnDraw()`

`fnDraw()` will redraw the table with the latest parameters.